# How to launch java application from Dock, Mac

Tags: java, macos, dock

I have created a Java Swing application. It works fine.

I have created application file (.app) for that application using jar bundler.

But the main problem is that my application does not open if I click it on the Dock. I am using Mac OS. How I can launch my application by clicking on Dock

Thanks
Sunil Kumar Sahoo

Comment: @Sunil Kumar Sahoo: I've got a Java Swing app package as a .app and all I need to do to launch it from the dock is to drop once the .app on the dock.  Then I can simply click on it and it opens fine.  What exactly isn't working?

Comment: Do you get an error or a warning message ?

Comment: No, I didnot get any error. I think is there anything left from my side to implement or handle Mac Dock event?

Comment: Take a look at the Console(?) (Konsole on my german mac). Any application output/error should be there.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Apple's [`JavaApplicationStub`](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/JavaLP/JavaToMac3/), diagnostic output from the launch process may be obtained as follows:

```
$ export JAVA_LAUNCHER_VERBOSE
$ ./your.app/Contents/MacOS/JavaApplicationStub
```

Here's a working [example](http://robotchase.sourceforge.net/).