# Apple .app (build with Ant's JarBundler) won't run

Tags: java, macos, ant, jarbundler

I build my app with the following `build.xml`
When I click on release/MyApp.app, it won't run!!!

But when I do

```
java -jar release/MyApp.app/Contents/Resources/Java/helloworld.jar
```

the executable (a Windows) does come up, meaning the `helloworld.jar` is built correctly.
But for some reason, the `app` doesn't know to load it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="App Builder" default="build_app" basedir=".">

  <taskdef name="jarbundler"
           classname="net.sourceforge.jarbundler.JarBundler" />

  <target name="build_app">
    <jarbundler dir="release"
            name="MyApp"
            mainclass="com.test" 
            jar="helloworld.jar" />
  </target>
</project>
```

Does anyone know what is wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: When you use JarBundler the `.app` package requires a Java application stub. Did you add that? http://informagen.com/JarBundler/StubFile.html

Comment: See also this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2929159/230513).

Answer (score 0):

+1 to trashgod.  When testing this (from your previous question), my app wouldn't start.  It was because the Stub was using Java 6 instead of Java 7 ... go figure.  Once I compiled my files down to Java 6, it worked fine.

Also, make sure that you are including all the dependent Jar files...

I used this as my target...

```
<target name="default">
    <delete dir="package" failonerror="false"/>
    <mkdir dir="package"/>
    <jarbundler dir="package"
                name="Cars"
                mainclass="testanimation10.TestAnimation10">
        <jarfileset dir="dist">
            <include name="**/*.jar" />
            <!--<exclude name="**/CVS" />-->
        </jarfileset>
    </jarbundler>
```

**Updated**

I downloaded [Java Application Bundler](http://java.net/projects/appbundler) from java.net, which seems to be the replacement for Apple's bundler and following the basic instructions from [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/packagingAppsForMac.html) and was able to build a bundle that was capable of running binaries compiled under Java 7