# Launch Java program with .command

Tags: java, shell, command-line, terminal

I'm trying to launch a Java program (a video game, specifically) from the command line. Because of (something) I can't figure out how to get the game to output to Terminal in any way when I launch it with the app bundle.

To rectify that, I'm trying to write a .command that I and other users can use to open the file from Terminal, but automatically so less tech-savvy users don't need to deal with typing out paths and such in Terminal (and to save me time trying to explain it day in and day out).

I'm hoping for an all in one file that will do it with a simple double click.

In my Terminal I can simply type:

```
~/Library/Application\ Support/Steam/SteamApps/common/GameFolder/Game.app/Contents/MacOS/JavaApplicationStub
```

And that launches it fine, with output. Trying to set this as a .command file:

```
#!/bin/bash
~/Library/Application\ Support/Steam/SteamApps/common/GameFolder/Game.app/Contents/MacOS/JavaApplicationStub
```

Works, but won't run without the user doing chmod +x for it (which brings me back to the original problem, of having to make end users do things on command line that they might not be comfortable with).

I'd be open to either being told what I'm doing wrong, or if anyone has a suggestion for a better method I'd be open to that as well. Nota Bene, I haven't done shell script work since I was 14 or so, and that's been… quite a while. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `JAVA_LAUNCHER_VERBOSE`, shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2929159/230513).

Comment: offtopic:There are many packaging solutions to create binaries to launch java program. http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/ for example.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow trashgod. JAVA_LAUNCHER_VERBOSE appears to be a command line function from what I can tell, making it irrelevant- when launched from command line, Java spits output anyways.

Comment: Not sure how that's relevant Jayan. I already have an app bundle packaged and it launches with one click. As I said in the OP, the problem is it doesn't give any real-time output, which is what I need.

Comment: If this is your Java code make it log to syslog - then that can be made visible in  Console.app